# How to join 2 tabels in order to receive all the data needed

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have 2 queries:

```
/*+ ETLM
{
  depend:{
    replace:[
      {
        name:"table_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
*/
SELECT 

case_id,
x,
x,
x,
x,
x

FROM table.1


WHERE resolved_date between TO_DATE ('2020/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD') and to_date('2020/12/31','YYYY/MM/DD')
AND ASSIGNED_TO_GROUP IN ('First Group')
```

and

```
/*+ ETLM
{
  depend:{
    replace:[
      {
      name:"table_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
*/



SELECT

x,
x,
x,
case_id,
x,
x


FROM table_2

WHERE create_date between TO_DATE ('2020/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD') and to_date('2020/12/31','YYYY/MM/DD')
```

So basically I need all the info in the tables, case_id being the primary key on table_1. How can I join them to receive all the data and use only the WHERE's from the table_1?

PS: the tables are spectrum enabled on redshift

I tried

```
Select
x
x
x
FROM table_1 

JOIN table_2 ON table_1.case_id = table_2.case_id
Select 
x
x
x
FROM table_2

Where table_1.resolved_date between ...
AND table_1.assigned_group...
```

But it seems that I get an error on the second SELECT statement

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What sample? I have let's say case_id, location, state on the 1st table and case_id, user, flag on the second table and I want to return case_id, location, state, user, flag, based on the case_id.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Ok, I read it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
table_1.x,
table_1.x,
table_1.x,
table_2.x,
table_2.x,
table_2.x
FROM table_1 

JOIN table_2 ON table_1.case_id = table_2.case_id

Where table_1.resolved_date between ...
AND table_1.assigned_group...
```